# There is no location option in simulator debug area

Tags: swift, xcode, geolocation, ios-simulator, xcode12

Hey guys so I created a I'm trying to use location setting in app, but for some reason when I open up the simulator and go to the debug option, there is no "Location" menu item for me to select, not sure its like this, I have update 12.1 but even on the previous version it was not displaying, how would I get it to appear? thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is no `location` feature in **debug** option, but it's inside **Features** of iOS Simulator.

---

Example to use it:

Open Location menu from **Features**, select **Custom Location**
[image: Open location menu from Features]

Set custom Location
[image]

Xcode 12.2

Comment: Thank you very much it was helpful

Comment: @TristamLearner happy to hear it! Please mark my question as correct if it fixed you issue.